# __cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup feature test macro missing in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20, clang++

I'm trying to test the existence of the [heterogeneous lookup for unordered_map](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r1.html) using the corresponding feature test macro, which according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros) should be `__cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup`.

```
$ g++ -v
gcc version 11.1.0 (GCC)

$ clang++ -v
clang version 13.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 372237487e2494f37ad204b7a0eea3425d919e66)

$ cat featuretest.cpp
#include <version>

#ifdef __cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup
#warning "Macro defined"
#else
#warning "Macro not defined"
#endif

int main() {}
```

Running the above with both GCC and Clang outputs:

```
$ clang++ featuretest.cpp -std=c++2a
featuretest.cpp:6:2: warning: "Macro not defined" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Macro not defined"
 ^
1 warning generated.

$ g++ featuretest.cpp -std=c++2a
featuretest.cpp:6:2: warning: #warning "Macro not defined" [-Wcpp]
    6 | #warning "Macro not defined"
      |  ^~~~~~~
```

However, I know for sure the feature is implemented because I've used it. E.g., Clang's `$HOME/opt/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/unordered_map.h` has:

```
#if __cplusplus > 201703L
       template<typename _Kt>
     auto
     find(const _Kt& __x) const -> decltype(_M_h._M_find_tr(__x))
     { return _M_h._M_find_tr(__x); }
```

Are these feature test macros not required to be present? My guess it's to do with my GCC/Clang installtions?

I did find a `<version>` file that contained the macro in clang's include path `$HOME/opt/include/c++/v1/version`, but that's apparently not being used. I got `g++` via `apt` on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If the feature test macro doesn't exist, then perhaps that feature isn't available? That's kind of how feature test macros are supposed to work, if they are defined the feature exists, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just realized the original phrasing might've implied that. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: Have you tried including `<unordered_map>` or `<unordered_set>` in your test program? Considering that those are the header files listed for that macro.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yup same thing, no matter how I include it

Comment: Then that feature isn't included. There's really not much more to say.

Comment: The `__cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup` is required to be defined, but only in gcc-11.2 and clang-trunk that have fully implemented [p0919](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r3.html), see [this](https://godbolt.org/z/TEE3EfcnT).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Still weird because [libstdc++ status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) says:
`Heterogeneous lookup for unordered containers P0919R3 11.1 __cpp_lib_generic_unordered_lookup >= 201811`


Maybe something wrong with the docs or a packaging inconsistency. Also I can already use the feature in 11.0, but I'm guessing it's techincally "experimental" in this version.